# Python List to Pandas Dataframe - Concatenate Lists

Tags: python, list, pandas, formatting

I'm trying to combine two sets of data that I have in list format, and I'm trying to convert them both to pandas, then merge them, in order to eventually export a CSV. I've been trying to convert them to pandas, but I seem to be unable do so without losing data. A data sample is as follows -

```
[[     CAPITL LMP  CENTRL LMP  DUNWOD LMP  GENESE LMP    H Q LMP  HUD VL 
LMP  \
Hour                                                                          
00     33.694545   -2.760000   20.277273   -3.484545  -6.530000   20.450909   
01     17.832500   16.915833   17.795833   16.416667  16.032500   17.795833   
02     21.685833   20.530833   21.690833   19.920000  19.520833   21.681667   
03     26.000000    1.942500   17.254167    1.354167  -0.737500
```

I have tried something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(sales)
```

but when I do I lose all of the data in each row and I only have the column titles.

```
        0            1            2            3         4            5   \
0   CAPITL LMP   CENTRL LMP   DUNWOD LMP   GENESE LMP   H Q LMP   HUD VL LMP   
1  CAPITL Loss  CENTRL Loss  DUNWOD Loss  GENESE Loss  H Q Loss  HUD VL Loss   
2   CAPITL Con   CENTRL Con   DUNWOD Con   GENESE Con   H Q Con   HUD VL Con
```

I don't understand why this is happening, and any help is greatly appreciated. Sales is the top List of data, and it goes on beyond what I have pasted to include other columns (the titles of which you can see become aggregated above after using the dataframe.from idea...

Comment: This input data is not a python list.  Your code sample is incomplete. What is `sales`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Maybe print sales (or a slice of sales) and include it in your question so we can see how it's structured and maybe get idea of the problem

Comment: I've updated the question to try to explain further what sales represents. Hope that clarifies things a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment, I will provide it as an answer. You didn't provide a proper input, so it is hard to answer your question. However, I suspect that perhaps your dataset is not a list- take a look at the diagram of 4 different types of data for creating a DataFrame in this link: `http://pbpython.com/pandas-list-dict.html` this should work for you